# Question format seems hidden

Tags: discussion, questions, formatting

I just came through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58080257/how-to-add-two-filter-security-metadata-source-bean-in-same-context) today. At first look, it seems *too broad /unclear*. So I choose the *close vote*.

> [image]

After that, I thought that how SO allowed the user to ask a *one-line question*. So I click on edit and there was some code:

> [image]

The questions are:

- Why is the code portion not visible on the screen?
- Will editing the question and format the code (still failed at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) IMO) be the appropriate action?
- Or should I keep the close vote?

Comment: No matter how much effort we put into the help center, someone somewhere still won't read it, will forget to format the code, and appear to have an awful question when half of it is formatted away. if you want my advice, if you're on a tag where XML/HTML is used, and you stumble over a question that feels like it's missing something, click "edit" every time. If there's nothing there, close and optionally downvote and move on. If there is something, format the code and re-judge the question. If the question is otherwise fine with the code, you should retract your close vote on this question.

Comment: But there ought to be automatic detection of this very common error. The assumption of an (unknown) HTML tag to be ignored is way too primitive. It is a job for software.